# How to construct F# tuple type?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, r.net

Given the following type in F#

```
type Message = string * AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression>
```

How can I construct it ? Great stuff over at [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/overview-of-types-in-fsharp/), but I cannot find how to construct the new 'algebraic data type' `Message`.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
member x.Evaluate(expression: string, ?timeout) : SymbolicExpression =        
    agent.PostAndReply(fun c -> Message (expression,c), ?timeout=timeout)
```

I'm trying to expose the `MailboxProcessor` to C# and try to keep as much F# specific types away from the C# code. Therefore I'm trying to only take in a string and resturn a `SymbolicExpression` type ( from the `RDotNet` namespace ).

**Update**

Ok - so here's the full source.

```
open RDotNet

type Message = string * AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression>

type RInterfaceAgent(dllpath:string, rhome:string) =
    let engine = 
        RDotNet.REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(dllpath,rhome)
        RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance()

    let agent = MailboxProcessor<Message>.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec messageLoop n = async {
            let! (msg, channel) = inbox.Receive()
            engine.Evaluate(msg) |> channel.Reply
            do! messageLoop (n+1)
        }
        messageLoop 0
    )      

    member x.Evaluate(ex: string, ?timeout) : SymbolicExpression =        
        agent.PostAndReply((fun c -> Message (ex, c)), ?timeout=timeout)
```

Error message in this part: `(fun c -> Message (ex, c))` is:

> The value or constructor Message is not defined

[image: Signature]

Comment: Hi @ildjarn - thanks, but doesn't work. The type doesn't have a constructor - which is my problem. I'm looking for a solution to either add it, or do without, or in case I'm doing something stupid - do something else.

Comment: your `Message` is an alias for a tuple so you could just pass the tuple by itself or change the type `Message` to a DU e.g. `type Message = | Message of string * AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression>`

Comment: Why does your error message show `expression` instead of `ex`?

Comment: @Guvante because I refactored

Comment: @spike: You have a parameter named `ex` and you are passing in `expression` in the screenshot.

Comment: Hey @Guvante - thanks for pointing that out - I know - I had expression first but in order to prevent possible name clashes I refactored to ex. That wasn't the problem though - I made sure of that. I've got it up and running now thanks to some of the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you defined it, `Message` is only an alias for `Tuple<String, AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression>>` so it does not have an explicit constructor, any Tuple of the specified pair is a Message. You can just return a `(expression,c)`, instead of `Message (expression,c)`

What you are looking for is probably making it a record type:

> type Message = {str: String; expression: AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression> }

And then you'll only be able to construct it by explicitly naming the fields

> {str=... ;expression = ... }

Comment: thanks - but that doesn't work. I think it requires an instance of `Message` ( see the attached pic )

Comment: Hey - you were right as it turns out. Don't know what happened when I first tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your message definition is just a type alias for tuple. The compiler treats the types as equivalent - and so you can sometimes see `Message` in the tool tips and sometimes the expanded definition.

```
type Message = string * AsyncReplyChannel<SymbolicExpression>
```

Assuming this is the type and `agent` is of type `MailboxProcessor<Message>`, the following way of sending it to the agent should work:

```
member x.Evaluate(ex: string, ?timeout) : SymbolicExpression =        
    agent.PostAndReply((fun c -> (ex, c)), ?timeout=timeout)
```

The bit `(ex, c)` simply creates a tuple (which is what `Message` is).
Note that you need brackets around the lambda function (which is missing in your screenshot).

Also, unfortunately, optional parameters in F# and C# work differently. So, if you're writing C# friendly API, you'll need to use the C# style optional parameters, which would look roughly like this:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

member x.Evaluate(ex:string, [<Optional>]timeout:Nullable<int>) = 
  let timeout = if timeout.HasValue then Some(timeout.Value) else None
  (...)
```

Comment: Thanks - very helpful! I've been reading a *lot* of our stuff on C#/F# lately - for instance on contra- and covariance.